# Is there a way to create optional line break without using float?

Tags: html, css

I have a web form that contains several inputs, some of which are positioned next to another while others are on a new line. Example of which is shown:

```
<h3>Max and Min Value</h3>
Max: <input name=max_value type=number>* Min: <input name=min_value type=number>

<h3>Overall Value</h3>
Overall: <input name=overall type=number>
```

I want to position `max_value` and `min_value` such that they are on the same line if the browser window is wide enough, else break to a new line at `*` position. I understand that I can get the job done by enclosing them in wrapper elements and using `float:left` to style both. But that would affect the flow of the whole document unless I introduce additional spacer elements.

Is there an alternative way to create the optional line break without affecting the flow of the document?

Comment: Use inline-block style to group the elements into sub group. Please refer my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping your `Min` input in a div and specifying `display: inline-block` should do the trick:

```
<h3>Max and Min Value</h3> 
Max: <input name=max_value type=number>* <div style="display: inline-block">Min: <input name=min_value type=number></div>

<h3>Overall Value</h3> 
Overall: <input name=overall type=number>
```

Comment: This is great! Didn't know it could be so simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `white-space: nowrap` to keep the input and labels together:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    label { white-space: nowrap; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Max and Min Value</h3>
  <label>Max: <input name=max_value type=number>*</label> <label>Min: <input name=min_value type=number></label>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's odd, I used Firefox (v13) to verify that it worked.
Edit: Tested it in Chrome as well and it appears to work.

Comment: @Victor - I am on the latest version of FF/Chrome and the `Min` field dislays on the 2nd line always on both.

Comment: @James: Try changing the width property of body to 450px. The current value (250px) will force wrapping.

Comment: @VictorHallberg The `Min` field now displays on the same line but doesn't wrap when the browser is collapsed.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow I am testing on the latest versions of Chrome & FF (FF v14.0.1 / Chrome v20.0.1132.57 m)

Comment: Updated example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjsqm/). The dynamic example should "re-wrap" when the frame becomes too small.

Comment: @James, yes, it doesn't wrap. I agree your solution is better.

Comment: The width specification prevents dynamic wrapping. I originally added them to demonstrate how it would look without having to resize the browser but removed them now to avoid confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

You could forbid line breaks with css:

```
.nobr  { white-space:nowrap; }
```

so your resulting code would look like:

```
<h3>Max and Min Value</h3>
<span class="nobr">Max: <input name=max_value type=number></span> <span class="nobr">Min: <input name=min_value type=number></span>

<h3>Overall Value</h3>
Overall: <input name=overall type=number>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you need to do is, after floating the new wrapper elements to the left, to `clear: left` (or `both`) the `<h3>`tags. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type='text/css'>
.block
{
display:inline-block;
padding-left:5px;
margin:5px 0px;
}
</style>

<h3>Max and Min Value</h3>
<div class='block'>Max: <input name=max_value type=number></div><div class='block'> Min: <input name=min_value type=number></div>


<h3>Overall Value</h3>
Overall: <input name=overall type=number>
```

Hope this works for you.